# Change value of text input on jsp when hashmap key is chosen from a select

Tags: jsp, hashmap, key

I have hashmap `promotableFiles` being passed to my jsp from a java class. In one drop down I have the user selecting the key, which is the file name. What I want is my second input, a readonly text input to update with the value from that key.

How can I change the value to the value of my key in my hashmap on a different input field? Jquery and Javascript is not out of the question.

```
<p>
<span>File: </span>
<select name="txtFilePromote" id="txtFilePromote"> 
    <option value="select" selected="selected">--Select File--</option>
    <c:forEach var="promoteFiles" items="${promotableFiles}">
        <option value="${promoteFiles.key}">${promoteFiles.key}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
</p>
<p>
    <span>Control Number:</span>
    <input type="text" name="txtControlNum" id="txtControlNum" size="10" value="" readonly/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, suppose you have an entry

```
[key1->value1]
```

When user selects `key1` from dropdown, you want to show the `value1` in textfield

For that assign option's value attribute as values from the hashmap and not the keys.

To do that, change

```
<option value="${promoteFiles.key}">${promoteFiles.key}</option>
```

to

```
<option value="${promoteFiles.value}">${promoteFiles.key}</option>
```

Or if you don't want to show `value1`, and show `key1` only, then don't do the above change.

And then jquery code is pretty simple. Add below code in your JS, and offcourse import the jquery dependencies in your JSP

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtFilePromote").change(function () {
        $("#txtControlNum").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Sample Demo -> [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w0gmz9mk/1/)

Comment: Thanks! That is simpler than I was making it out to be.